# How to fix an amplitude cutoff?

Tags: sound, volume

I'm having a problem trying to find out the right terminology for a problem to be able to fix it: I record audio over a radio transceiver from the mic port.

However by mistake, I recorded the sound from an audio while the volume was up too high, causing the amplitude to be chipped.

**What is the professional definition for this problem? Is there a method to fix this using Audacity?**

Here are the links for the sound files to assist your analysis.

Original: https://www.dropbox.com/s/brqq7uec2fx4pbq/test1.mp3

Recorded: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0pm17oy5rjy963/test1n.mp3

Comment: It's called clipping and is already treated in this question: http://avp.stackexchange.com/q/7215/2178

Comment: It describes my problem precisely. Thanks!